# Gstreamer buffer convert with cuda

Tags: multithreading, cuda, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to convert (try to set red channel to 0) gstreamer buffer using cuda. There is a snippet of code:

```
__global__ void transform( guint8 *data, int width ){
  uint x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  uint y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;
  uint pixPos = (y * width + x) * 4;
  data[pixPos + 2] = 0; // BGRA format
}

void simple_transform( guint8 *data, int width, int height ){
  guint8 *d_data;
  guint8 size = width * height * 4;

  checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_data, size ) );
  // copy original buffer into device
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy( d_data, data, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );

  dim3 threads = dim3(8, 8);
  dim3 blocks = dim3(width / threads.x, height / threads.y);

  // execute kernel
  transform<<< blocks, threads >>>( d_data, width );

  // move back converted data to original buffer
  checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy( data, d_data, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );

  cudaFree( d_data );
}
```

The problem is that video shows without any changes. I want to see blue-green picture, but can't. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think this should be the mistake. `guint8 size = width * height * 4;`. Shouldn't it be `size_t size = width * height * 4;`

Comment: Thanks! Now converter works as excepted.

Comment: I have posted the solution as an answer, you may accept it so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the total size of the image to a variable of type `guint8`

```
guint8 size = width * height * 4;
```

This is able to accommodate values up to 255 only. Size must be assigned to a variable of larger data type (say `size_t`).

```
size_t size = width * height * 4;
```